# Postgres server is not visible in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql

I have a newly instantiated postgres server that I generated from a database dump:

```
psql -U postgres postgres < dump.sql
```

Verifying the installation

```
sudo pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql
```

/postgresql-10-main.log

Now I then enter pgadmin by typing

```
pgadmin4
```

In the terminal and no databases are available. I'm using postgres 10(the same as the server for the dump) and ubuntu 16. My postgres setup is pretty standard but with postgres/pg_hba.conf changed to trusted.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved it by followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhG2L4OWRY8

I set the postgres password and added a new localhost server with the correct password.